# PlanningEntity field with an InverseRelationShadowVariable in a ProblemFact is not updated - Optaplanner

Tags: java, quarkus, optaplanner

I have a *ProblemFact* `AgentAvailability` which reference a shadow planning entity `Agent` (`Agent` has no *PlanningVariable*, only an *InverseRelationShadowVariable* referencing the *PlanningEntity* `Shift`)

Here is my class definitions:

`Shift.class`

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Shift extends AbstractPersistable implements Comparable<Shift> {

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "agentRange" }, nullable = true)
private Agent agent;
private Spot spot;

private LocalDateTime startDateTime;
private LocalDateTime endDateTime;

//Constructor, getters, setters and JPA annotations removed for clarity
```

`Agent.class`

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Agent implements Comparable<Agent> {

@PlanningId
private long registrationNumber;
private String username;
private boolean pro;

private SortedSet<Skill> skillSet = new TreeSet<>();

@InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "agent")
private SortedSet<Shift> shiftSet = new TreeSet<>();

//Constructor, getters, setters and JPA annotations removed for clarity
```

`AgentAvailability.class`

```
public class AgentAvailability extends AbstractPersistable implements Comparable<AgentAvailability> {

private Agent agent;
private LocalDateTime startDateTime;
private LocalDateTime endDateTime;

//Constructor, getters, setters and JPA annotations removed for clarity
```

and here is my Solution definition:

`Schedule.class`

```
@PlanningSolution
public class Schedule extends AbstractPersistable {

// ...
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "agentRange")
private List<Agent> agentList = new ArrayList<>();

@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
private List<AgentAvailability> agentAvailabilities = new ArrayList<>();

@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
private List<Shift> shifts = new ArrayList<>();

// ...
//Constructor, getters, setters and JPA annotations removed for clarity
```

the *inverseShadowVariable* is working as expected: when an `Agent` is assigned to a `Shift`, the `shiftSet` from the assigned `Agent` is updated with this shift.

The problem is with the field `agent` from `AgentAvailability`.

From my understanding, when Optaplanner clones the solution, according to [documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.12.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#cloningASolution), it reuses instances for ProblemFacts, and uses cloning for planning entities.

Since `AgentAvailability` is a Fact I assume it's reused (and in debugger view, this is the case, instance is the same between initial problem and bestSolution found)

`Agent` from `Schedule` are correctly cloned with their `shiftSet` to the solution too.

But the problem is that `agent` field in `AgentAvailability` is still the `Agent` instance from the original problem.

Therefore, the field `shiftSet` of `agent` in `AgentAvailability` instances is still empty.

It is the case at the end in the bestSolution found, but also during computing.

Therefore, I cannot use a *constraint* like this:

```
 return constraintFactory.from(AgentAvailability.class)
                            .groupBy(AgentAvailability::getAgent, count())
                            .filter((agent, availabilities) -> availabilities - agent.getShiftSet().size() > 0)
.penalizeConfigurableLong(ShiftSchedulingConstraintConfiguration.PRO_HAS_SHIFT, (agent, availabilities) -> availabilities - agent.getShiftSet().size());
```

since `agent.getShiftSet().size()` always return 0 even when the agent has been assigned to shifts.

A possible Workaround would be to use a from(Agent.class) clause, and join with AgentAvailabilities and Shift to "rebuild" the shiftSet from the `Agent` Entity. but is there any way to "clone" the shiftSet from `Agent` entities in the `Agent` of `AgentAvailability` so I can use agent field from `AgentAvailability` with updated `shiftSet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with your model. You can not expect `AgentAvailability` to both be and not be cloned. If `AgentAvailability` is a problem fact, it will not be cloned, and therefore the value of `agent` will not be changed.

(Side note: maybe we should detect if an entity is referenced from a planning fact, and fail fast? I don't see how such a situation leads to anything but trouble.)

There are several solutions to this problem. I recommend you make `Agent` a problem fact and create a new entity `AgentAssignment`, mapping 1-to-1 to `Agent`. In this model, you can freely reference `Agent` fact instances in other facts.

The constraint then becomes relatively easy to write.

```
from(AgentAssignment.class)
    .join(AgentAvailability.class,
          Joiners.equal(
              AgentAssignment::getAgent,
              AgentAvailability::getAgent))
    .groupBy(
         (agentAssignment, agentAvailability) -> agentAssignment, 
         countBi())
    .filter((agentAssignment, availabilities) -> availabilities - agentAssignment.getShiftSet().size() > 0)
    ...
```

Comment: It makes sens, thanks for your suggestion, I try that

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, add a `@DeepPlanningClone` annotation on `AgentAvailability`:

```
@DeepPlanningClone
public class AgentAvailability ... { ... }
```

But Lukas's answer is better.

Comment: I thought I already tried that but I must have not... since it actually works with this annotation. 
I will stick with Lukas's answer since you both agree on it. Thanks for your help, and your product ;)